# PySimpleGUI _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY enviroment variable - raspberry

Tags: tkinter, raspbian, pysimplegui

im on Raspbian LITE, RaspberryPi3modelB, installed python3.7 and PySimpleGUI.
Set framebuffer and set mirroring on HDMI.

but after running simple almost example python file:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('DarkAmber') # Add a little color to your windows
realTemp = 0

buttonLayout = [ [sg.Button(button_text="comon", border_width=3), sg.Button('Off'), sg.VSeparator(), sg.Button('On'), sg.Button('Off'), sg.VSeparator(), sg.Button('On'), sg.Button('Off'), sg.VSeparator(), sg.Button('On'), sg.Button('Off')] ]

# All the stuff inside your window. This is the PSG magic code compactor...
layout = [ [sg.Text('Current temperature: ',realTemp)],
[sg.HorizontalSeparator()],
[sg.Text('Temperature Setting', font=('Any 14'))],
#[sg.Button('+'), sg.Button('-')],
[sg.Slider(range=(0, 45), default_value=realTemp, size=(60, 10), orientation="h",
enable_events=True, key="slider")],
[sg.Text(' ', font=('Any 14'))],
[buttonLayout],
[sg.Cancel()]]

# Create the Window
#window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, no_titlebar=True, location=(0,0), size=(800,480), keep_on_top=True)
#window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout).Finalize()
#window.Maximize()

# Event Loop to process "events"
while True:
event, values = window.read()
if event == "slider":
realTemp = values["slider"]
elif event == "Left:37" or event == "Right:39":
if event == "Left:37":
realTemp -= 1
else:
realTemp += 1
window.Element("slider").Update(realTemp)

if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
break

window.close()
```

i get output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "agitator.py", line 27, in <module>
    event, values = window.read()
  File "/home/qres/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10075, in read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
  File "/home/qres/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10146, in _read
    self._Show()
  File "/home/qres/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 9886, in _Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "/home/qres/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16817, in StartupTK
    _get_hidden_master_root()
  File "/home/qres/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16704, in _get_hidden_master_root
    Window.hidden_master_root = tk.Tk()
  File "/home/qres/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2020, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I tried plenty of manuals, but still stuck.

What i want is to run python program with (PySimple)GUI
(in fullScreen, no closing button) with touch LCD display.
Preferably not installed RaspbianGUI.
Now the display is not connected, thats why i set HDMI to mirror.

Please does anyone had this issue or know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you run `xterm` or `xclock`? This likely has nothing to do with tkinter and everything to do with not configuring your system to be able to create windows.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for comment. when i tried either of them there was 'command not found'. Am i missing something elementary?

Comment: I don't know. Most systems that use X11 come with those programs. Maybe the Raspbian LITE, RaspberryPi3modelB doesn't.

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I think ill try to use the regular raspbian (with GUI installed), set to start only without graphical interface and try to run it in there. But if anyone would have idea how to set graphical python program just in console, please let me know. thank you very much :)